# Using a feature in a function in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, layers, vector, function

I want to use in the get_pdf_data function the data loaded in the "imobile" vector so that I can perform operations with the "imobile" vector.

The code I'm trying to do this with is:

```
  var vectorSource = {
       teren: new ol.source.Vector(),
       constructii: new ol.source.Vector(),
       uat: new ol.source.Vector(),
       search: new ol.source.Vector()
 };
         
var imobile = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource.teren, declutter: true });

   

      function get_pdf_data(idPdf, idPrimarie){
                console.log('DATA PDF');
                $('#container_respok').hide();
                $('.container_hide').show();
                $('.container_cauta').hide();
                                        
                $('#map').css('width', '50%');
                $('#map').css('float', 'right');
                                        
                var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
                                        
      imobile.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature){
              feature.setId(feature.get('text'));
                                                
                                                    
              var data = "";
              if($('#etc_tarla').is(":checked")){ data = "T:"+feature.get('tarla')+"  "; }
              if($('#etc_parcela').is(":checked")){ data = data+"P:"+feature.get('parcela')+"  "; }
              if($('#etc_suprafata').is(":checked")){ data = data+"S:"+feature.get('suprafata')+"MP.  "; }
              if($('#etc_proprietari').is(":checked")){ data = data+"P:"+feature.get('proprietari')+"  "; }
              if($('#etc_eterra').is(":checked")){ data = data+"C.F.:"+feature.get('e_terra')+"  "; }
                                                    
         if(feature.get('text') == idPdf){
         console.log('GASITTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT');
            
         var feature = imobile.getSource().getFeatureById(idPdf); 
         //console.log(feature);
                                                            
         selected_stile.getText().setText(data);
         feature.setStyle(selected_stile);
         ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
        }                                                     
      });
                                        
         map.getView().fit(extent, {size: map.getSize()});
                                        
     }
```

And the error received is the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: imobile.getSource is not a function
> at get_pdf_data (harta2.php: 3238)
> at meniu_search (harta2.php: 3280)
> at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (harta2.php: 1)

This is very useful to me because when I resize the map to 50% width automatically I have to look for a terrain in the respective map with idPdf and then to center the map on it

Comment: Please edit your question and make your code more readable by making those huge indents more decent.

Comment: I apologize :(:(

Comment: Sorry, but if you just try to find the matching brackets in the above code, they do not match. And also, what is `array[i]` in the statement `var feature = imobile.getSource().getFeatureById(array[i]);`. Where is `i` coming from?

Comment: Sorry this is good line: var feature = imobile.getSource().getFeatureById(idPdf);

Comment: If your code is really as above, you shouldn't get the mentioned error. Go into browser debugger, set a breakpoint at the `imobile.getSource()....` line and check `imobile` value/content.